# почему mgr выдается как nameError

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста. Почему mgr в в эмуляторе выдается как nemeError. Дело в том что когда я пишу код в саблайне:

```py
import pyowm
owm=pyowm.OWM("720972b15a226c0a4923e1a99a633a46")

place=input("Город в котором бы вы хотели узнать погоду?:")

observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

print(w)
```

Но потом когда хочу вывести это на эмуляторе, то в эмуляторе как положено задается вопрос:"Город в котором бы вы хотели узнать погоду?:" Но потом когда я пишу либо Москва либо Moskow, то в эмуляторе пишется: in  obserwation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
AtributteError:'OWM' objekt has no atributte "weather_at_place"

Но когда я в соблайне пишу:

```py
import pyowm
owm=pyowm.OWM("720972b15a226c0a4923e1a99a633a46")

place=input("Город в котором бы вы хотели узнать погоду?:")

observation = owm.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

print(w)
```

то есть вместо `'owm'`, я уже пишу `'mgr'`, то в эмуляторе после того как том будет написано: "Город в котором бы вы хотели узнать погоду?: и после того как я напишу Москва или Moskow, то в эмуляторе написано:

```
in <module> obserwation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
NameError: name `'mgr'` is not definet
```

Почему такое происходит? Такое ощущение что ему не нравится слово или `'owm'` или `'mgr'`.
И `'owm'` и `'mgr'`
Не могу разобрабраться, помогите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Кто такой "соблайн"? Откуда у вас берётся объект `mgr`? Что за эмулятор? И вообще - проверяйте версии библиотек. Возможно, у вас разные версии ,библиотеки `pyowm` в разных местах, поэтому в одном месте у неё есть метод `weather_at_place`, а в другом нет.

Comment: Соблайн- это sublime text. А вывожу все на эмуляторе ConEmu

Comment: Вот где у вас `mgr` - приведите полный код с этим вариантом. Вы же `mgr` откуда-то берёте, что-то туда присваиваете предварительно?

Comment: import pyowm
owm=pyowm.OWM("720972b15a226c0a4923e1a99a633a46", )

place=input("Город в котором бы вы хотели узнать погоду?:")


observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

Comment: Ну вот `mgr` - это обычная переменная. Чтобы её использовать нужно ей что-то присвоить. Откуда тут взялась эта переменная?

Comment: АльхадулиЛЛЯХ ошибка нашлась. Там короче после команды: import pyowm
owm=pyowm.OWM("720972b15a226c0a4923e1a99a633a46",  ) надо было внизу добавить:mgr=owm.weather_manager(). Я этого не сделал. Просто я смотрел видео Хаоди, он сам так тоже не делал, хотя копировал это с сайта github.com  , но потом я стал внимательнее смотреть на том же сайте и обнаружил вот эту строку: mgr=owm.weather_manager(), хотя у него в видео я такого не видел. По ходу он старую версию pyowm показывал. Ладно ребята, спасибо за вам помощь. Я по вашим подсказкам тоже ориентировался.